# Creating new function in SQL adding numbers

Tags: sql, combinations, formula, new-operator, addition

I was asked to create function in Transact-SQL which should add numbers in range and show every possible combination.
Example:

```
exec AAA 2,10
result:
1+9
8+2
3+7
4+6
5+5
exec AAA 3,10
result:
7+2+1
5+2+3
4+5+1
```

I've never done anything like this in SQL is it possible?

Comment: That does not sound like a problem you should resolve in SQL

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Not with that syntax -- it would make `AAA` a stored procedure rather than a function. A function would look like `select * from dbo.AAA(2, 10)`. Several aspects of this problem make it uncomfortable to solve in T-SQL, even in a stored procedure -- it's a nice intellectual exercise, but not something you'd really want to do in T-SQL in a production setting.